# Removing DocuSign Other Actions "About DocuSign" link

Tags: docusignapi

We have requirement to remove **About DocuSign** link in Other Actions menu. I tried making changes in resource file, but not able to succeed. Can we handle is at code level?. Could any of you help me out on this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can!
It’s a setting on the brand. The text and the link can also be modified if they want their own link.

```
  <HeaderLinkSystemOverview>
    <Hide>True</Hide>
  </HeaderLinkSystemOverview>
```